# Finding MxN matrices with a non-zero values within a "large" matrix (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, matrix

Would you have any suggestions of finding M x N matrices in the original matrix using MATLAB that have non-zero values and also more than one row and column (M > 1 & N > 1).

Example: Main matrix:

```
0   10  1   4   0   6   0   17
16  0   18  2   5   1   18  0
20  20  9   12  16  10  0   11
5   6   7   0   13  0   8   6
2   14  20  8   19  6   18  1
8   20  10  15  13  11  6   5
11  0   0   18  0   5   0   8
12  6   2   0   15  6   13  0
0   11  12  0   8   0   4   20
```

This is how the results should look like:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: This is not a code writing service. What have you tried so far and what is your problem with that implementation?

Comment: I would approach this converting the matrix to logical, convolving with an `M`×`N` mask of ones, and checking where the result is `M*N`

Comment: How large is "large"? Is brute force too slow?

Comment: @beaker In "99 %" cases not larger than 500 x 500 elements. I tried to understand a rather mathematical approach that I found here https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/304017-identify-a-matrix-within-a-matrix if it could be maybe applicable.